# Trying to query for Facebook profiles and sort them into a ListView Android

Tags: android, facebook, listview, facebook-graph-api, android-listview

I am using the Facebook Graph API to request a list of Facebook profiles and return them in a ListView displaying both names and profile pictures.  I have two EditText fields in my main acitivty to enter both first and second names.  A button starts my ListViewActivity when clicked and the names are passed.  The ListView inflates and the request is sent to Facebook and each row in the ListView is updated using a custom adapter.

The problem is, I suspect, a memory leak.  It is very temperamental as in, it would work once or twice if I'm lucky and any other attempts to update the ListView wouldn't work, the activity would remain blank.  It doesn't work for some more common names either.

Below is my ListViewActivity:

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

public String firstname, secondname;
URL imageURL;
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {"Description"};

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    loadData();
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void loadData() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    firstname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstname");
    secondname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("secondname");

    if(session==null){                      
        session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
    } else if (session.isOpened()) {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "name, picture, url, id");
        params.putString("limit", "10");

        Request request = new Request(session, "search?q="+ firstname + "%20" + secondname + "&limit=10&type=user&fields=name,picture", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                JSONArray jArray = null;
                imageURL = null;

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                    jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject element = null;
                        element = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        imageURL = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ element.get("id") +"/picture?type=large");
                        names.add(element.getString("name").toString());
                        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream()));
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        thread.start();
                        thread.join();
                        if (bitmaps.size() == jArray.length()) {
                            for (int j=0; j<jArray.length(); j++) {
                                RowItem item = new RowItem(bitmaps.get(j), names.get(j), descriptions[0]);
                                rowItems.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    System.out.println("JSON EXCEPTION:"+ e);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    } else {
        Log.d("close", " "); 
    } 
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

Would appreciate it if someone could help spot a memory leak (if that is indeed the issue because i'm getting between 7 - 10% free) and advise whether there is a better way of implementing this? Thanks

EDIT: Just to clarify I'm updating the list by going back to the main activity to enter a new name in the edit text fields and clicking the button to start the list view again

Answer (score 0):

Does scaling the images help any?

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
```

I added in those two lines at line 67

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

public String firstname, secondname;
URL imageURL;
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {"Description"};

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    loadData();
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void loadData() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    firstname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstname");
    secondname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("secondname");

    if(session==null){                      
        session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
    } else if (session.isOpened()) {

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "name, picture, url, id");
        params.putString("limit", "10");

        Request request = new Request(session, "search?q="+ firstname + "%20" + secondname + "&limit=10&type=user&fields=name,picture", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                JSONArray jArray = null;
                imageURL = null;

                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                    jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject element = null;
                        element = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        imageURL = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ element.get("id") +"/picture?type=large");
                        names.add(element.getString("name").toString());
                        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                try {
                                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                    options.inSampleSize = 2;
                                    bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream()));
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        thread.start();
                        thread.join();
                        if (bitmaps.size() == jArray.length()) {
                            for (int j=0; j<jArray.length(); j++) {
                                RowItem item = new RowItem(bitmaps.get(j), names.get(j), descriptions[0]);
                                rowItems.add(item);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    System.out.println("JSON EXCEPTION:"+ e);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    } else {
        Log.d("close", " "); 
    } 
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
}
```